# Use of nested ternary expression in .zshrc prompt configuration

Tags: zsh, prompt

what is wrong with my RPS1 expression

```
RPS1='%(t.[Ding!].%(t30.[Dong!].[%T]))'
```

Explanation:

I want to get `[Ding!]` if it is 11am, `[Dong!]` if it is 11:30am and if both is not true just normal time like `[11:33]`. But what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is `%[<number>](X.true.false)`, not `%(X[<number>].true.false)`.

So:

```
RPS1='%(t.[Ding!].%30(t.[Dong!].[%T]))'
```